# How to implement Client Credentials Grant with Spring WebFlux 6.X and Spring OAuth2 Client ignoring current principal

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, spring-oauth2

I am trying to use the native support of Spring WebFlux to setup a WebClient with Client Credentials Grant but I would like to ignore the principal in the Security Context.

The problem I am facing is that with the implementation below, for each different user, a new access token will be requested to the IDP. I would like the access token to be shared across all the users.

Here is a snippet of my current configuration.

```
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        var clientRegistrationService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
        var oauth2Client =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                        new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                                clientRegistrationRepository, clientRegistrationService));

        oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("my-client");

        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth2Client)
                //...
                .build();
    }
```

By the way, by creating a wrapper around InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService I was able to solve the issue by simply ignoring the principal argument and providing a static one. However, I would like to use native support and wonder if the use case I am trying to implement is legitimate.